# How can I Integrate an exponential function using trapezium rule with n varying intervals

Tags: c

Please I really need help. I keep running my program but no matter what loop I try or intervals I put, program just keeps running forever.
Here's the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define w 2004
#define n 10
float fn(float x)
{
exp(-(w*(x*x)));
return exp(-(w*(x*x)));
}
main()
{
int i;
float a=-1,b=1,s,y,h;
s=0;
done:
    n+10;
    if(n<=100){
        i=1;
        do{
            s=s+fn(a+i*h);
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        while(i<n-1);
        h=(b-a)/n;
        y=(fn(a)+fn(b)+2*s)*h/2;
        printf("\nThe value of y is=%0.4f\n", y);
        goto done;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ``n+10;`` does not make sense. You have to change it to ``n=n+10;`` or ``n+=10;`` so you change ``n`` every loop and program does not run forever. But your code has other major problems excepting this.

Comment: the statement 'n+10;` has no effect. You don't use the result. `n = n+10` also does not make sense, since `n` is a non-asignable constant.

Comment: `goto` does have its usages. But this here is just missleading and confusing. Use a `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks vital information. However, something like

```
while(i<n-1);
```

cannot be sane. None of the variables changes inside the loop, so it will loop forever (wasn't that what you noticed?).

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, I just didn't know where it came from. Thx.